# why does this return 3 in Python 3.x+?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
k=input().split()    
print(max(k))
```

input:

```
3 10
```

output:

```
3
```

Comment: Because `"3" > "10"`.  You're dealing with strings here, ordered alphabetically, not numbers.

Comment: `"3" > "10"`, because this is a comparison between strings.

Answer (score 1):

Because string "3" is greater than string "10", for the same reason that string "z" is greater than "a"; alphabetic rather than numeric sorting. The first 20 numbers, as strings, sort like:

1 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 2 20 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

This is because strings are sorted from the leftmost character to the rightmost, so for example 2 and 20 are tied on the first character and the next one sorts it out, whereas the 3 in 3 is greater than the 2 in 20

Answer (score 1):

```
# this will do string comparison 
k=input().split()
print(max(k))

# to make integers
# go element by element
k = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
print(max(k))
# using map
k = map(int, input().split())
print(max(k))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify that the input is an integer using the `int()` function, otherwise python will automatically view it as a `string`.

Strings have their own way of sorting numbers which is completely different from integers.